# How to have IP address as a parameter in jwt.sign

Tags: javascript, authentication, ip, jwt

I have id, username, name, but I also want the IP address.

Here's the current function:

;

I'm using the MEAN stack and I want to incorporate IP address in my method of authentication. Currently the token is signed as above, using the user model which has parameters id, name, username.

Comment: This question is severely incomplete. What's `user`? In which kind of server are you running? I see a mongodb tag but nothing else explaining what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I've expanded upon it a bit. All i want is IP address to be a part of the token.

Comment: Do you have the Express request object available?

Comment: Yes I'm using expresss

Comment: Ok, I'm writing an answer. Give me 10 minutes

Comment: Why did you delete the function?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you're in your application's login controller and you're just generating the token.

This examples uses a [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) database instead of your mongodb, but you and anyone else reading should be able to adapt it to any model.

The relevant part to this question is `ip: req.connection.remoteAddress` at line 17.

If your createToken function isn't inside the middleware, you'll need to either pass it the whole request object or at least the IP.

```
server.post("/login", function(req, res, next) {

    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    var user = lowdb.get("user").find((x) => { return x.username == username; }).value();

    if (!user) {
        res.status(401).json({ message: "Authentication failed. User not found." });
        req.connection.destroy(); //Make sure processing can't continue even if somewhere along the stack someone accidentally called next() more than once
    } else if (user) {
        var auth = user.authenticationData;

        if( _cryptCompare(auth.salt + "|" + password, auth.hash) ){
            var DURATION = 3600*8;

            var token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id, roles: user.roles, ip: req.connection.remoteAddress }, _SECRET, {expiresIn: DURATION});
            var expiration = new Date();                
            expiration.setSeconds(expiration.getSeconds() + DURATION);

            res.json({ token: token, expires: expiration });
        } else {
            res.status(401).json({ message: "Authentication failed. Wrong password." });
            req.connection.destroy(); //Make sure processing can't continue even if somewhere along the stack someone accidentally called next() more than once
        }
    }
}
);

function _cryptCompare(str1, str2){
    return bcrypt.compareSync(str1, str2);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The remote IP address can be accessed using `req.headers['x-forwarded-for']` in Express.

```
function createToken(user) {
  var token = jwt.sign({
    id: user._id,
    name: user.name,
    username: user.username,
    ipaddress: req.headers['x-forwarded-for']
  }, secretKey, {
    expiresIn: 120
  });
  return token;
```

Comment: This is only necessary if there is actually a proxy between you and the client, and OP didn't mention having one. Also, I'll point out that if there is any other proxy between you and the client you shouldn't trust the header to contain the actual adress of the originating client. Headers can easily be spoofed.